# What is the standard protocol for creating permanent stocks from freeze-dried bacteria?

Tags: cell-culture

I've received freeze-dried bacteria that I intend to use for a study I'm doing on slime mold; however, I've never dealt with freeze-dried, only frozen, bacterial cells. After reconstituting these cells in 6mL media, is it alright to split this in to halves and place one aliquot into DMSO or glycerol to make a permanent stock right away? Or is it best to plate, isolate, suspend, grow, and then make a permanent stock?

Comment: I was under the impression that glycerol stocks should be made from log phase cells. Therefore, I would definitely grow up the cells before freezing a glycerol stock.

Comment: I am not sure, if the cells would survive this procedure. I would reconstitute them first and then make glycerol or DMSO (which I prefer for easier handling) from fresh cultures.